# How to get current URL domain for react for server side rendering?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

How do you get the current URL domain for react for server side rendering? Since the window object isn't accessible during SSR. React router location only gives the pathname and not the domain.

Comment: You can access window inside useEffect(()=> console.log(window.location.hostname))

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this to your app's codebase:

```
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
  global.window = {}
}
```

You can add this to startup file which is mostly index.js